# DB25 to TTL logic (voltage control)

Tags: arduino, cables, ttl, attenuator, arduino-uno

I am trying to control a 6-bit digital step attenuator for a project, with an Arduino (here, Arduino Due or Arduino Mega). The given attenuator has a software to control it. So, I connected the attenuator to the parallel port of the computer (with a DB25)  and gave instructions through the software. The attenuator was working fine.

**But the problem is that I want to control this attenuator with the help of an Arduino, so please suggest me a method through which I can extract direct voltage from the DB25 through a wire (or otherwise) and insert it on an Arduino.**

The cable connected to the attenuator. (click on  "Case STyle")

https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=CBL-5FT-MPD%2B

This cable came with DB25 on the other end to communicate with the parallel port of the computer.

P.S: I have already coded the Arduino to run the Digital Attenuator by assuming a direct connection between them. (through voltages)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) The DB25 is TTL, as far as I know, and it's working so why do you need "the help of" a micro-controller? (2) There is no data on that link - it's a catalog page that gives no clue what the product is or does. You should post a link to the datasheet instead. I think you could edit and improve your question to clarify what you're trying to do, where you are stuck and what your question is. (There is no question mark anywhere in your post.)

Comment: Made changes. Please check again.

Comment: To even attempt an answer to this, we need to see the datasheet of the attenuator you are trying to control.  The drawing of the cable does not help unless we know what the cable connects to.  Considering that the cable you linked to has "SPI" in the part description; I suspect that the attenuator may not be controlled by voltage, but rather using the SPI protocol.  Of course, that's impossible to know without a datasheet.

Comment: Well, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the PC and replace it with an Arduino, you need to go through certain steps:

1. Understand how the attenuator is controlled - by some combination of reading at the datasheet and perhaps studying the existing software (if you have access to the source).
2. Learn how to program an Arduino (if you don't already know).
3. Combine steps 1 and 2 to write an Arduino driver for the attenuator.

That's about as specific as an answer to this question can be without actually doing your design work for you.

Comment: So, I removed the attenuator connection to the computer and with then changed the value of attenuation from the PC, through the software. Now, with the help of a multimeter, I noted down the pins which were high when I gave a given command. For example, I switched on only the LSB (0.5dB) through the software and checked voltage on each pin. In this way, I found out the pattern of voltage for each bit. 

Hence, now Can I use a male-female DB25 and then solder wires on the male side accroding to the pattern I found?

Comment: you really need to look at the datasheet for the attenuator device for this.

Comment: It is useless. They have just mentioned the cable type, that's all.